# Click Event to fire when using back and forward browser buttons

Tags: jquery, browser-history, hashchange, jquery-click-event

I'm using a click event to show a hidden inline div. I'm currently using Ben Alman's Jquery hashchange event http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/ so that the forward and backward browser buttons will show the hashtag links in the URL. The issue is the hidden divs stay hidden when you go forward and backwards and I need them to show.

HTML:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#link1">Link 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#link2">Link 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#link3">Link 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#link4"><Link 4</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<div id="div3"></div>
<div id="div4"></div>
```

Script:

```
$("#link1").click(function() {
    $("#div1").fadeIn("400");
    $("#div2, #div3, #div4").hide(); 
});
$("#link2").click(function() {
    $("#div2").fadeIn("400");
    $("#div1, #div3, #div4").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with changing your hashchange plugin I can reccomend jQuery Address.
See here http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/

In order to catch hash change you write:

```
$.address.change(function(event) {
    // Your code here
});
```

The good thing about this hashchange function is that the plugin ensures it always gets called after **document.ready**, so you don't have to about this thing.

**event.pathNames[0]** will be the hash you need. You can use it inside the change hadnler and show the desired divs.

**See this demo** (*I think it does exactly what you need. Check it with the browser buttons*): 
 http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/samples/api/ 
**Sample usage:** http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/docs/#sample-usage

Comment: I'm pretty new to JQuery so I'm having a hard time understanding how to implement this based of the sample/demo. I've added rel="address:/#link1" to the links but I don't understand what to do with my script.